# Ubuntu fails to boot after upgrade from 16 to 18 due to failed systemd-udevd.service

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, 16.10, systemd, udev

After dist-upgrade from Ubuntu 16 to 18 my system fails to boot. My Ubuntu works in VirtualBox.

Output of `journalctl -b`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please format your post in a proper way - use plain text instead of images!

Comment: I tried 3 online OCRs and 3 of them gave bad results. Pls, do not suggest me type that from keyboard. Get text files from virtual machine is a problem too, because of network does not work. Sorry.